# Pulling words from a string

Tags: string

So I made this algorithm to pull words out of a string of words without picking up punctuation and spaces. It works perfectly up until the very end where it stops at the second to last word and then gives an out of bounds error. Let me know if you need to see any other methods.

```
public static double totalSentiment(String fileName)
    {
        String list = textToString(fileName);
        double total = 0;
        int start = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < sentiment.size(); i++)
        {
            int stop = list.indexOf(' ', start+1);
            String word = list.substring(start, stop);

            int puncC = word.indexOf(',');
            int puncP = word.indexOf('.');
            int puncE = word.indexOf('!');
            int puncQ = word.indexOf('?');

            String polishedWord;
            if(puncC != -1)
            {
                polishedWord = word.substring(0, puncC);
                total += sentimentVal(polishedWord);
                System.out.println(i + ") " + polishedWord);
            }
            else if(puncP != -1)
            {
                polishedWord = word.substring(0, puncP);
                total += sentimentVal(polishedWord);
                System.out.println(i + ") " + polishedWord);
            }
            else if(puncE != -1)
            {
                polishedWord = word.substring(0, puncE);
                total += sentimentVal(polishedWord);
                System.out.println(i + ") " + polishedWord);
            }
            else if(puncQ != -1)
            {
                polishedWord = word.substring(0, puncQ);
                total += sentimentVal(polishedWord);
                System.out.println(i + ") " + polishedWord);
            }
            else
            {
                total += sentimentVal(word);
                System.out.println(i + ") " + word);
            }
            start = stop;
        }

        return total;
    }
```

Comment: somewhere inside the for loop it is trying to access an index beyond the end, this is common when you are operating not just on the for loop index "i" but looking ahead.  for example : list.indexOf(' ', start+1);  is start always going to be at least 1 + 1 less than the length of list?

Comment: Uh hm. Yeah it is.